What is the best way to implement named colors in Rust?
(I'm a Rust newbie coming from a strong C/C++/Java background.)
In Rust, I would like to create "enum" like variables that are constant, ideally initialized at compile time.
For example, to store colors including red, green and blue components and access them by name, I would like to do something like:
struct MyColor {
  Red : u8,
  Green : u8,
  Blue : u9,
}

#[repr(MyColor)]
enum PrimaryColors {
  Red (255,0,0)
  Green (0,255,0)
  Blue (0, 0, 255)
}

Then in my program I could access
PrimaryColors::Red::Green
and get 0,  or possibly do something like
(r,g,b) = PrimaryColors::Red.
I might also use this approach to store a list of states with capitals, population, etc. associated with each.
I've written numerous small programs, trying to understand the errors and suggestions, but I'm starting to repeat myself.
I wouuld appreciate guidance from experts, and am open to solutions that don't involve enums.

You can do this with associated consts:
struct MyColor {
    red: u8,
    green: u8,
    blue: u8,
}

impl MyColor {
    pub const fn new(red: u8, green: u8, blue: u8) -> Self {
        Self { red, green, blue }
    }

    pub const RED: Self = Self::new(255, 0, 0);
    pub const GREEN: Self = Self::new(0, 255, 0);
    pub const BLUE: Self = Self::new(0, 0, 255);
}

Now you can use MyColor::RED, for example.  If you want them available under some other name, such as PrimaryColors in your example, then just use a module:
mod PrimaryColors {
    use super::MyColor;

    pub const RED: MyColor = MyColor::new(255, 0, 0);
    pub const GREEN: MyColor = MyColor::new(0, 255, 0);
    pub const BLUE: MyColor = MyColor::new(0, 0, 255);
}


You can even destructure the color into variables: let MyColor { red: r, green: g, blue: b } = PrimaryColors::RED;. Playground

Thank you!  That also taught me something new about "new"!
